# Localizing Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to localize a Xamarin Forms app. I followed all the steps included here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/localization/

However, in the Android Emulator, after changing the default language, the strings do not get displayed, they remain the default language. On the device the app doesn't even launch.

Steps taken so far:
1) tried breakpoint (BP) in the main launcher, it skipped the BP and entered the main page
2) tried BP on the Localize class, it doesn't reach it
3) tried BP on the Device.OS check, skips it.

The resource files in Visual Studio are the following:

```
AppResources.resx
AppResources.fr.resx
AppResources.es.resx
```

Anyone ever succeeded localizing a Xamarin Forms app before ? I need some assistance with this as Visual Studio does not raise any exception ...

UPDATE 1 :

The resource files in Visual Studio are the following:

```
AppResources.resx
AppResources.fr_FR.resx
AppResources.es_ES.resx
```

UPDATE 2:

After recent suggestions and modifications I have the following exception: Markup extension not found.

This is disturbing as the markup extension class is there.

Comment: Did you check if the locale really changed after you changed the device language? like this: `var lang = Resources.Configuration.Locale; // eg. "es_ES"` as referenced [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/localization/)

Comment: Hello Kurt, yes I did, still the same result . I will update the question with this.

Comment: Since you are using the emulator, I assume you are using the debug build? Localization is not supported in debug mode if you check that page. Meanwhile, after changing your device's language, I think you need to fully restart the app (close it completely first, and then reopen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

The problem was in the declaration of the extension. In a PCL project, the following took place:

a) the TranslateExtension class is located in a subfolder named Pages

b) initial declaration was

```
xmlns:languages="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"
```

c) the following declaration solved the problem:

```
xmlns:languages="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages;assembly=MyApp"
```

along with language code naming conventions of the .resx files as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

> [Doesn't work in DEBUG mode (Android only)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/localization/#Doesnt_work_in_DEBUG_mode_Android_only)
>
> If the translated strings are working in your RELEASE Android builds
>   but not while debugging, right-click on the Android Project and select
>   Options > Build > Android Build and ensure that the Fast assembly
>   deployment is NOT ticked. This option causes problems with loading
>   resources and should not be used if you are testing localized apps.

Comment: Fast deployment is not ticked Jason. However now it seems that VS will not hit ANY breakpoint I set. EDIT: fixed the debugger, the culture gets returned properly, however the exception raised is that the markup extension was not found.

Answer (score 0):

**2021 UPDATE**

All the current answers are not valid anymore! You need to add resources. Right click your xamarin forms project (Not xamarin android or ios) => Go to project properties ==> Resources ==> Add Resource.

This will create a "Properties" Folder and a resources.resx file which you can delete if you want to.

Then follow the [official microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows) by creating a AppResources.resx and other language files (such as AppResources.ar.resx file for arabic). All these files **MUST  BE** in the properties folder.

Then, in your XAML page, declare the namespace as:

```
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:YourProject.Properties"
```

Then simply use:

```
<Label Text="{x:Static res:AppResources.Address}" >
```

This will use the corresponding Language files depending on what language the device is using. If the language is not supported it will use the defulat file (AppResources.res)

FIUH!!! Wasted one hour to solve this!!!